# Prove $\left|\frac1{x^2}\int_0^x\sin\frac1tdt\right|<1$

Tags: calculus, special-functions

I want to prove $$\left|\frac1{x^2}\int_0^x\sin\frac1tdt\right|<1,\ x\ne0$$
I set $$f(x)=\left|\frac1{x^2}\int_0^x\sin\frac1tdt\right|$$
And I found that $$f\left(\frac1x\right)=\left|x^2\operatorname{Ci}(|x|)-x\sin x\right|$$
As $f(x)=f(-x)$, I can assume $x>0$.
I noticed that $$x^2\operatorname{Ci}(x)-x\sin x\sim\cos x,\ x\to\infty$$
So $\limsup\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=1$.
But how can I prove $x^2\operatorname{Ci}(x)-x\sin x<1$?

Comment: Note that you only need to show that when $x\leq{}1$ since if $F(x)=\int_0^xsin\frac{1}{t}dt$ then by the mean value theorem there exists $x_0\in{}(0,x): \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=F'(x_0)$ thus $|\frac{1}{x}sin\frac{1}{t}|\leq{}|\frac{1}{x}|<1$ for $x<1$.